# Select 10 rows where sold='false' from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on an IPN for PayPal, and I need to know how to select a certain amount of rows where sold='false'

Comment: You work with PayPal and dont know about the basics of MySQL?

Comment: First of all, is false u mean , a boolean?

Comment: Before asking questions search google....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE sold='false' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where sold='false' limit 10
```

OR

```
select * from table where sold='false' limit M,N
```

this query fetches data starts from Mth row to N number of records

.

Comment: No. Or it should be `limit M, N`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10 * from table where sold='false'
```